# Sublime Text 2: Editing associated filetypes in Plist.info won't work

Tags: macos, osx-lion, file-types, plist, sublime-text-2

I edit lots of **.sass, .scss, html.twig** files. And so I wanted to **associate** these with Sublime Text 2. Because by default some of them get the "binary"-icon, some the "blank sheet"-icon which sucks in terms of clarity in the folders. I want them to use the CSS and HTML **icons** Sublime uses for .**css and .html** files. Therefore I opened the **Info.plist** in the Package Contents and edited it like that:

```
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>SASS</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
   <array>
      <string>sass</string>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
   <string>CSS</string>
</dict>
```

and for html.twig and email.md.twig

```
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>HTML</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
   <array>
      <string>html</string>
      <string>html.twig</string>
      <string>email.md.twig</string>
      <string>htm</string>
      <string>shtml</string>
      <string>xhtml</string>
      <string>phtml</string>
      <string>inc</string>
      <string>tpl</string>
      <string>tmpl</string>
      <string>tpl</string>
      <string>ctp</string>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
   <string>HTML</string>
</dict>
```

(FYI, I followed: [How to set an icon for a file type on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/178316/how-to-set-an-icon-for-a-file-type-on-mac))
Notice, that I use `CFBundleTypeIconFile`: HTML and CSS, so the icons definitely exist (since they work with .css and .html).

But after closing and moving the whole App to the `~/Desktop` launching it and moving it back to `~/Applications`, launching it again, nothing happens. I also tried rebooting OS X.

I'm also sure, that I don't have already set a custom icon to these files (via the Info-Dialog). I created some new test.sass etc. files on my desktop to check that.

Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here? And is it even a good idea to edit the Plist.info anyway? What happens when the App gets updated?

**Mainquestion:** What am I doing wrong here? ;-)

**Or:** Is there a different way to associate the correct icons for (e.g.) all .sass-files (and not separately for each single file)

THANKS!

Comment: To clarify, the files are associated with the Sublime Text 2 program and open in it when double-clicked?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RLXU7.png). [Here's a screenshot of the Info.plist values used](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjBX.png). Have you tried doing this step by step? It could be possible OS X cannot handle two file extensions (`html.twig`?) and therefore ignores the edited Info.plist file. Maybe try just `twig` instead.

Comment: Weird. I'll try it on another Mac tomorrow and come back to you. Thanks for testing it yourself.

Comment: Please keep me informed. Make sure to add `@DanielBeck` to your comment so I'll get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use TotalFinder you need to restart it by typing `killall Finder` in the Terminal. It seams that TotalFinder has its own icon cache (damn, should have checked that). The second thing I changed, was that I put the SASS-block on top of the `CFBundleTypeIconFile` array like @DanielBeck did when he tried to reproduce the problem.

The third thing is, like @DanielBeck recommended totally correct: Use just twig instead of xxx.twig since filetypes are read from right to left. `html.twig` would be a file named `html` with the extension `twig`.