# set different default applications for opening a file with a certain extension depending on the directory it's in

Tags: macos

I want to open all txt files in my home directory with emacs, but not all the others with text edit, is that possible? How could it be done?

Comment: XEmacs or Aquamacs, or yet another emacs program?

Comment: I use gnu emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Automator* and create a new *application*. Add a single *Run Shell Script* action that receives input *as arguments*, and has the following script code:

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    # just exit if there are no files to open
    exit 0
fi

# check the location of the first file to determine what to do
if [[ "${1/$HOME/}" != "$1" ]] ; then
    # $HOME (e.g. /Users/danielbeck) was found in the file path
    open -a TextMate "$@"
else
    open -a TextEdit "$@"
fi
```

Save as e.g. "Conditional Open Text Files"

Open the *Get Info* dialog of a `.txt` file and select it to open with this newly created program. Then, click *Change All…*.

This will cause all text files to open with this script application, which looks at the file path and decides based on that whether to open the files in TextMate or TextEdit. Use the application name of your particular emacs instead to make this work with e.g. Aquamacs.

If you want to get a nicer icon than the default "unknown document" icon, follow [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/225534/22317).