# macOS – Create an icon for all of one file type

Tags: macos, icons, macos-sierra

How can I set an icon for a specific file type to be used for **all of those files** on macOS Sierra? (not High Sierra).
I have seen some tutorials, most of which do not help, [including a very in-depth tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/178316/how-to-set-an-icon-for-a-file-type-on-mac), that is unfortunately outdated (TextMate now uses standard XML but I don't really undertstand the language), and I cannot follow.
The files that I would like to change are [.3dsx](https://fileinfo.com/extension/3dsx) files, [.cia](https://fileinfo.com/extension/cia) files, and [.3ds](https://fileinfo.com/extension/3ds) (second type) files. I know the trick where you select the item, press CMD + I and click on the icon and paste the icon, but that only changes the icon for that item, and I would like to change the icon for all files. I already have the icons ready, I have no problem with creating the files.
There's one problem, though. These three file types are not openable by any programs I have. macOS lists no programs to open them with, and I do not know of any programs that can open them, and this is why I cannot use any of the aforementioned tutorials.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The icon is dictated by whichever program opens the file right? Then couldn't you change the icon for the program of a given file type?

Comment: Read above. "these three file types are not openable by any programs I have."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RCDefaultApp](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14618/rcdefaultapp) preference pane to associate any file type/extension with the application of your choosing. The file type/extension will then use the icons associated with the selected application.

While the RCDefaultApp is very old it still works well on macOS 10.12

The [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) library can be used to set default applications on macOS as well.