# MacOS Monterey - not desktop icon, but icon for different RUNNING firefox profiles

Tags: macos, firefox, icons

Rather new to MacOS (monterey here) though I'm a linux guru for 2 decades, and a UNIX Guru from 3 decades ago. So my question might be trite.

Icons for items on the desktop is working for 2 firefox profiles. BUT when each are running, still see the usual firefox icon and name ("Firefox").

I found [How can I change an application icon in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/37811/how-can-i-change-an-application-icon-in-mac-os-x) but that just gives what I already have - desktop icons.

There are other superuser questions, but they are far out of date, and all links from those threads are 404. Any modern solutions?

Many thanks in advance.

[long time reader, first-time poster]

Answer (score 0):

Both profiles are running in the same app instance, therefore will always have the same icon.

If you run two distinct instances by duplicating the app itself, then they will still have the same app signature & the OS cannot differentiate between them.
The only way to realistically achieve 'separation' is to run two different apps - either literally [eg FF & Chrome] or by separating their identities before compile.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning "the Apple way" and finding it rather restrictive in many ways, to my surprise. If I ever figure out some zebra solution, I'll come back and share my insight(s).